# Saving printed values in for() function as variable?

Tags: r

I'm really new to R and I'm still trying to wrap my head around for() functions. My sample dput for my data (MergedData) is linked [here](http://pastebin.com/0kACv391) (I apologize for the length; I tried to shorten it as much as possible). I'm working on a small project, and I have the following function:

```
new.trend <- function(MergedData)
{
  ret <- as.list(rep(NA, length(MergedData))) 
  ma.sig <- ma.crossover(MergedData)
  pricebreak <- price.channel(MergedData)
  sig <- intersect(which((ma.sig[1,])==1), which(!pricebreak[1,]==0))
  for (i in sig) { #Calculates output variables based on active signals
    x <- MergedData[[i]]
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by=x[,1])
    dev20 <- (x[,4]-SMA(x[,4], n=20))/x[,4]*100
    dev50 <- (x[,4]-SMA(x[,4], n=50))/x[,4]*100
    RSI <- RSI(x[,4], n=14)
    ret[[i]]<- na.omit(merge(tail(dev20, n=1L), tail(dev50, n=1L), tail(RSI, n=1L)))
  }
  na.omit(print(ret))
}
print(new.trend(MergedData))
```

***The issue/problem***

return(ret) is returning this:

```
> new.trend(MergedData)
[[1]]
             EUR.LAST EUR.LAST.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.6968559  0.3526983 44.68176

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
             GBP.LAST GBP.LAST.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.1920461   1.027927 52.27664

[[4]]
            CHF.OPEN CHF.OPEN.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.5066387 -0.7241689 52.56533

[[5]]
[1] NA

[[6]]
[1] NA

[[7]]
[1] NA

[[8]]
[1] NA

[[9]]
[1] NA

[[10]]
[1] NA

[[11]]
[1] NA

[[12]]
[1] NA

[[13]]
           PLN.CLOSE PLN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.2824105   -1.569392 48.24069

[[14]]
[1] NA

[[15]]
           TRY.CLOSE TRY.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -2.315328  -0.2501765 42.52731

[[16]]
             ZAR.CLOSE ZAR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.09598239   -1.492148 46.06286

[[17]]
[1] NA

[[18]]
            CLP.CLOSE CLP.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.2433194   -2.112368 40.93616

[[19]]
[1] NA

[[20]]
           MXN.CLOSE MXN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -2.460443   -3.490762 34.67792

[[21]]
            PEN.CLOSE PEN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.4138617   -1.974541 37.84737

[[22]]
             CNY.CLOSE CNY.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.08749199  -0.5004658 44.39283

[[23]]
            IDR.CLOSE IDR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.4064827   -0.631571 35.91677

[[24]]
           INR.CLOSE INR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -1.291429   -1.594705 21.83156

[[25]]
            KRW.CLOSE KRW.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.8529425   -2.840274 34.61214

[[26]]
           MYR.CLOSE MYR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.1407816  -0.4020273 49.80231

[[27]]
           SGD.CLOSE SGD.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09  0.123548  -0.7103133 49.73621

[[28]]
           PHP.CLOSE PHP.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.1355443    0.236601 55.61772

[[29]]
           THB.CLOSE THB.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.518655   -1.396926 23.51997
```

But I want to retrieve what is printed in the for() function, such as this:

```
> for (i in sig) { #Calculates output variables based on active signals
+     x <- MergedData[[i]]
+     x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by=x[,1])
+     dev20 <- (x[,4]-SMA(x[,4], n=20))/x[,4]*100
+     dev50 <- (x[,4]-SMA(x[,4], n=50))/x[,4]*100
+     RSI <- RSI(x[,4], n=14)
+     print(ret[[i]]<- na.omit(merge(tail(dev20, n=1L), tail(dev50, n=1L), tail(RSI, n=1L))))
+ }- (x[,4]-SMA(x[,4], n=50))/x[,4]*100
        RSI <- RSI(x[,4], n=14)
        print(ret[[i]]<- na.omit(merge(tail(dev20, n=1L), tail(dev50, n=1L), tail(RSI, n=1L))))
      }

             EUR.LAST EUR.LAST.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.6968559  0.3526983 44.68176
             GBP.LAST GBP.LAST.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.1920461   1.027927 52.27664
            CHF.OPEN CHF.OPEN.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.5066387 -0.7241689 52.56533
           PLN.CLOSE PLN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.2824105   -1.569392 48.24069
           TRY.CLOSE TRY.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -2.315328  -0.2501765 42.52731
             ZAR.CLOSE ZAR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.09598239   -1.492148 46.06286
            CLP.CLOSE CLP.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.2433194   -2.112368 40.93616
           MXN.CLOSE MXN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -2.460443   -3.490762 34.67792
            PEN.CLOSE PEN.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.4138617   -1.974541 37.84737
             CNY.CLOSE CNY.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.08749199  -0.5004658 44.39283
            IDR.CLOSE IDR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.4064827   -0.631571 35.91677
           INR.CLOSE INR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -1.291429   -1.594705 21.83156
            KRW.CLOSE KRW.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.8529425   -2.840274 34.61214
           MYR.CLOSE MYR.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.1407816  -0.4020273 49.80231
           SGD.CLOSE SGD.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09  0.123548  -0.7103133 49.73621
           PHP.CLOSE PHP.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 0.1355443    0.236601 55.61772
           THB.CLOSE THB.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-09 -0.518655   -1.396926 23.51997
```

Tips, suggestions and pointers would be much appreciated! I understand that a for() function may not be ideal, but it's the only way I know how to be able to cycle through only the MergedData values that correspond to the indices in sig.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I see. If you want to keep for loop you could, change:

```
 na.omit(print(ret))
```

to

```
lapply(ret, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason I'm still getting the same results as na.omit(print(ret))

Comment: I really appreciate the second attempt :), but it's giving me  "Error in `[.xts`(x, !is.na(x)) : 'i' or 'j' out of range". I've also tried na.omit(do.call(ret, merge)), but it returned an empty matrix.

Comment: hmm ... I tried to load the data with dget but R fails. Can you dump the data intead of dput?

Comment: @kwicher Sorry, deleted previous comment because I think it'll be easier to give you the actual data and the code I use to index in R. Here's the raw data https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByfLu_yIza89RnJQSnQtQ2Uzbnc/view?usp=sharing and here's the function that correctly organizes it: http://pastebin.com/NRaHyg83

Comment: sorry but things do not play together ... you are missing something in data/code you provide. Yuo really have to create the minimal complete example that recreates the error as a standalone script

Answer (score 0):

Try to use apply function to evaluate data frames or zoo time series.
In R its better to avoid constructions such as `ret <- as.list(rep(NA, length(MergedData))); ret[[i]]<-row`. Use `lapply` which produces list or `apply` which give you a matrix.

Consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
#create zoo object
z <- zoo(data.frame(column1 = c(1, 2, 3), column2 = c(5, 6, 7)), order.by = seq(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by = 'day', length.out = 3))
z
#create function to calculate each row
f <- function(row){
    row ^ 2
}
#apply function f to each row (MARGIN = 1) of zoo (z) object, transpose matrix and create zoo time series
res<-apply(z,MARGIN = 1,function (row) f(row)) %>% t %>% as.zoo(.,order.by=rownames(.))
res
class(res)
```

this will produce

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(zoo)
> #create zoo object
> z <- zoo(data.frame(column1 = c(1, 2, 3), column2 = c(5, 6, 7)), order.by = seq(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by = 'day', length.out = 3))
> z
        column1 column2
2017-01-01       1       5
2017-01-02       2       6
2017-01-03       3       7
> #create function to calculate each row
> f <- function(row){
+     row ^ 2
+ }
> #apply function f to each row (MARGIN = 1) of zoo (z) object, transpose matrix and create zoo time series
> res<-apply(z,MARGIN = 1,function (row) f(row)) %>% t %>% as.zoo(.,order.by=rownames(.))
> res
        column1 column2
2017-01-01       1      25
2017-01-02       4      36
2017-01-03       9      49
> class(res)
[1] "zoo"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I'm trying to become a better R programmer, so stylistic pointers are much appreciated :). Is there a reason apply is more favored over ret <- as.list(rep(NA, length(MergedData))); ret[[i]]<-r? I'm not familiar at the apply function, but I'll try my hand at it! Would a for() function be an appropriate function be place within apply/lapply? I really only want the function to run for certain indices of MergedColumn

Comment: 'apply' allows you to manage array indexes, it makes your code clear and short. You will avoid many mistskes that descend from usual arrays. 'for' loop is possible inside apply, but in R the vectorised solutions are more elegant, it is to save your time. Try to use vectors not cycles in R.

Comment: Note that this does not use anything from dplyr except `%>%` and that is imported from magrittr so `library(dplyr)` could be replaced with `library(magrittr)` to minimze dependencies.